# How does this differentiation come about ?

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, complex-numbers

The question is that: If $f(z)$ is analytic, show that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar z} = 0$

Now, assuming $f(z) = u + iv$
$\frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar z} = \frac{\partial}{\partial \bar z}(u + iv)$
What the book does is this:

$$
(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}.\frac{\partial x}{\partial \bar z} + \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}.\frac{\partial y} {\partial \bar z})
$$
for the $u$ part. Similarly for the $v$ part

Can someone please explain how that is done ?

Comment: the chain rule?

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan Please elaborate

Comment: $u = u(x,y)$ and $x = x(z,\overline{z}) = \frac{z+\overline{z}}{2}$, and similarly $y = y(z,\overline{z}) = \frac{z-\overline{z}}{2i}$. Now what does chain rule tell you about $\frac{\partial u}{\partial \overline{z}}$

Comment: @LittleChild As Prahlad said, it follows immediately from chain rule.

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan If your answer is right, please post it. I will accept it. And make it a lil bit more elaborate *I am slightly weak at math*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a function $u = u(x,y)$ of two variables. In turn, each *variable* is a function of two more variables, namely $z$ and $\overline{z}$. While you cannot write down $u$, you can write down $x$ and $y$ as
$$
x = \frac{z+\overline{z}}{2}, \qquad\text{ and }\qquad y = \frac{z-\overline{z}}{2i}
$$
Now you are looking to find $\frac{\partial u}{\partial \overline{z}}$. By the [Chain rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule), you get
$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}.\frac{\partial x}{\partial \bar z} + \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}.\frac{\partial y} {\partial \bar z}
$$
In other words, you are finding the rate of change of $u$ w.r.t $\overline{z}$ : This will depend on the rate of change of $u$ w.r.t. $x$ and $y$, which in turn change w.r.t. $\overline{z}$. The chain rule helps you compute how these rates compound.

(Note : Just think of $z$ and $\overline{z}$ as symbols here, and not as complex numbers, if that is what is confusing you!)

Comment: One thing that's confusing me here is that I thought a non-constant real-valued function was never complex-differentiable, so how can we write $\frac{\partial x}{\partial \bar{z}}$?

Comment: @EricAuld : We are not taking a complex derivative here (as you say, we cannot write $dx/d\overline{z}$. Just think of it as the limit of difference quotients.

Comment: In the difference quotients, is the denominator complex valued? If so, how is it distinct from the complex derivative?

Answer (score 0):

I think what they are doing is writing $u(x,y)$ as $u\left(\frac{z+\bar{z}}{2}, \frac{z-\bar{z}}{2i}\right)$. Once you write it like this, you can take $\partial_z u$ by doing what they do above. Are you familiar with the chain rule?

Comment: yes for real numbers. Never tried for complex numbers